# Glass Development Kit Javadoc in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, google-gdk

I am unable to add the Javadoc for the Google Glass Development Kit (GDK) to either Eclipse or Android Studio; I'd love to be able to reference the GDK documentation right inside my IDE instead of just referencing the [webpage](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/index).

Is there any way to do this? I'm aware of the typical way to add Javadoc to an Eclipse project, but I can't seem to find the actual documentation files for the GDK anywhere...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is none for the small number of Google glass specific classes. The majority of classes are simple Android. (I understand from a talk with Jenny Murphy that the Google glass specific classes are implemented in native language and the java is just wrapper code.)

Perhaps this will change with the next GDK release (briefly saw indications of testing an XE15.2 version in the glass gdk issues, though that is hidden now).